# PHP regex vs explode() for phone number

Tags: php, explode

I have been messing around with some regular expressions, and I ran into a small hiccup with a more complicated version of my phone number formatting.

Here's what I am working with:

$number1 = '+1 (123) 1234567';
$number1 = '+966 (1) 1234567 x555';

These strings are actually being output from the MySQL query I created, and I love it.
However, I'm making a simple php function to auto-format the subscribers number from  1234567 to 123-4567.

I'm not too concerned about any number that doesn't start with +1.  So I'm formatting US and Canadian numbers.

Here's what I attempted, if there was only 7 digits, and if the string starts with +1

```
<?php

function format_phonenumbers($phone){
    if(empty($phone)){ return ''; }

    $exploded = explode(' ',$phone);

    $countrycode = $exploded[0];
    $areacode = $exploded[1];
    $number = $exploded[2];
    $ext = (!empty($exploded[3])?$exploded[3]:'');

    if($countrycode=='+1'){
        $strphone = strlen($number);
        if ($strphone == 7) { // auto-format US PHones

            $prefix = substr($number,0,3);
            $suffix = substr($number,-4);

        }
        $phone = $countrycode.' '.$areacode.' '.$prefix.'-'.$suffix.' '.$ext;

    }

    return $phone;
}



echo format_phonenumbers('+1 (714) 1234567'); // US domestic
echo '<br>';
echo format_phonenumbers('+966 (1) 1234567 x555'); // international

?>
```

This formats what I need, but I'm curious if anyone believes I can do this in a better way. Like using a regex checker, that finds anything after the parenthesis, but before an extension, rather than using the explode() function.

Comment: `... output from a mysql query`... .how are the numbers stored in MySQL? If you've got mysql formatting the numbers from multiple fields, then simply output those individual fields so you don't have to UNDO what you just did in MySQL.

Comment: So wait, you'd like to take the string you already have in the database, and change its form into something more readable? (just so that I understand your question completely)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
function format_phonenumbers($phone)
{
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/([)]\s*)(\d{3,3}(\d+)/',
        function ($match) {
            return $match[1] . $match[2] . '-' . $match[3];
        },
        $phone
    );
}
```

This should work, but requires PHP 5.3.0 or higher (if not you'll have to use `create_function`). Its arguable if it is any better however.